# Dynamic (Variable) Identity assertion in apache knox

Tags: jdbc, knox-gateway, apache-knox

I want to connect to HiveServer2 through knox as a specific user (userX) and don't want any authentication. For this, I am using "Identity assertion" with "Anonymous authentication provider".

Inside my sandbox.xml (present in topologies), I have used this code :

```
<provider>
        <role>authentication</role>
        <name>Anonymous</name>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
</provider>
<provider>
        <role>identity-assertion</role>
        <name>Default</name>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <param>
        <name>principal.mapping</name>
        <value>anonymous=userX;</value>
        </param>
</provider>
```

This works fine, but I want the userX to be a variable and I want to receive this variable through the jdbc url command.

The command I am using :

```
beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://GATEWAY-HOST:GATEWAY-PORT/;ssl=true;sslTrustStore={gateway.jks location};trustStorePassword={master-key};transportMode=http;httpPath=gateway/sandbox/hive"
```

Say I want to establish the connection as 'UserABC', how can I achieve that?
How to pass this UserABC in the jdbc url and what changes are needed in sandbox.xml to pick that variable userId.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [HeaderPreAuth](https://knox.apache.org/books/knox-1-1-0/user-guide.html#Preauthenticated+SSO+Provider) federation provider for this, I would also echo the caution expressed in the documentation that you need a proper network security configured else this provider will leave gateway exposed to identity spoofing.